# How would a highly mutagenic (or shape-shifting) species have to adapt physiologically to achieve space travel?

Tags: biology, evolution, aliens, space-travel, adaptability

An idea I like to write about a lot is aliens that are dependant on their own biological evolution over technology. I was wondering what kind of adaptations a species that could rewrite their own genetic code at will for rapid adaptation and evolution would have to undertake in order to achieve space travel without relying on spaceships. What kind of biological armour/protection would they need? How would they evolve a propulsion system? And what crazy adaptation would be needed for explained biological warpspeed?

This is my first question so thanks for any responses.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Welcome to WB:SE.  Please understand that you've asked a primarily opinion-based series of questions that are too broad for a viable answer.  Curiously, as phrased, the only viable answer is "whatever is needed," since the creatures can rewrite their DNA to achieve anything they want.  Please consider reviewing our [Ask a Good Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: You will find interesting reading here on the topic of [space whales](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=space+whale)

Comment: The zergs from StarCraft2 might be a good reference point.

Comment: Hi Benji-Ninja - I love this theme, too bad it isn't suitable as a single question... There have already been several related questions in WorldBuilding (see my next comment) - You are encouraged to read those, and ask new questions to fill in the missing pieces for what interest you (it is also recommended to link your new questions to related existing questions - this improves the quality of both questions).

Comment: Related questions: [How would a biologically advanced race without technology leave their planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85612/756), [How could a creature get off a planet without technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/74840/756), [Can non-intelligent life naturally evolve the ability to space travel...](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/28658/756), [How might the spores of an interstellar lifeform navigate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/90457/756), [Biological Spaceships - Possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/9853/756)

Comment: Finally, in addition to @Kevinfu 's Zergs (why StarCraft 2 and not simply StarCraft, btw?), you may find references for this theme in WarHammer-40K [Tyranids](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Tyranids), Starship Troopers [Arachnids](http://starshiptroopers.wikia.com/wiki/Transport_Bug) (the TV series, not the excellent, but devoid of bio-starships, book), Robert L. Forward's Camellot 30K [keracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelot_30K), [Dyson Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_tree) and TV-Tropes [Living ship list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LivingShip). Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi Benji-Ninja. You're asking too many different questions at once. Stack Exchange works best with single questions that have answers which can be objectively judged as correct or incorrect. As discussed by @G0BLiN above (and as exemplified by the multitude of existing questions linked), you should narrow this down to a *single* question. Pick any one of these questions, do some research (a few minutes with your favorite search engine and Wikipedia can actually go a pretty long way for this), then ask a *specific* question about that one aspect and show us what you've learned in the meantime.